# How to hide current user's data from displayed Firebase data in Ionic App

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic3

My problem is that I'm displaying all data within the Firebase Database, but it is also including the data of the user who is currently logged in. For example, if a user's profile consists of: firstName = "Sasha", lastName = "Parks", language = "Creole", she will see her own profile on the displayed data.

How can I modify this code to hide her own data?

My page's ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ProfilePage } from '../profile/profile';

import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';

import { Profile } from '../../models/profile.interface';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-matches',
 templateUrl: 'matches.html'
})

export class MatchesPage {
 profile = {} as Profile;
 profileData: Observable<Profile[]>;

 goProfilematches = ProfilePage;

constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private db: AngularFireDatabase, 
   public navCtrl: NavController) {
}

ionViewWillLoad(){

this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(data => {

    if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
    this.profileData = this.db.list('profile/'+data.uid).valueChanges();
    } else {
  }
});
}   

}
```

The html:

```
<ion-header>
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons start>
  <button ion-button [navPush]="goProfilematches">
    <ion-icon name="contact"></ion-icon>
  </button>
  </ion-buttons>
 <ion-title>Matches</ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let profile of profileData | async">
    <h1>First Name: {{profile?.firstName}}</h1>
    <p>Last Name: {{profile?.lastName}}</p>
    <p>Language: {{profile?.language}}</p>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>

</ion-content>
```

The Firebase database is organised into the Authentication and the Real-time Database portions, where users sign up with their email and password, and then fill out a profile stored in the Real-time Database.

Any help is appreciated!
Any help is always appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You gotta add a variable in your ionViewWillLoad with the current user logged in,

```
var user_id = firebase.auth().currentUser;
```

and change the condition

```
  if (data && data.email && data.uid) {
```

to

```
if (data && data.email && data.uid && data.uid!=user_id) {
```